# Apache Camel Main-Class and its methods start, stop, run, suspend and resume

Tags: apache-camel

I am writing my first camel application. it is a standalone application with a main method. As starting point i used the maven camel java archetype. It provides a simple main method that calls `main.run()`.

Now i re-factored it a little bit and pulled the main.run out in a new class (and method) that will be my main-control of all camel stuff.
Now i want to create the "opposite" method of run(). At the moment i want to implement tests for single routs that start (run()) the context then wait (at the moment i am unsure how to wait 'til a route is finished) and the stop the context.

But now i discovered many method that could start and stop stuff all in Main class. The Jvadoc didn't help - that some methods are inherited doesn't make it easier ;-). So someone please tell me the exact meaning (or use case) for:

```
Main.run()
Main.start()
Main.stop()
Main.suspend()
Main.resume()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this page about the lifecycle of the various Camel services

- http://camel.apache.org/lifecycle

And for waiting until a route is finished, then you can check the inflight registry if there is any current in-flight exchanges to know if a route is finished.

- http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/InflightRepository.html

Comment: lifecycle describes all but not "run()". What does this do?

Answer (score 1):

We must separate the methods into 2 groups.
The first is the one described in the life cycle http://camel.apache.org/lifecycle
The second is composed of run and shutdown.

run runs indefinitely and can be stopped when invoking shutdown, the latter must be invoked in a different thread and sent before the run invocation.

Example:

```
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class ShutdownTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       Main camel = new Main();

       camel.addRouteBuilder( new MyRouteBuilder() );

       // In this case the thread will wait a certain time and then invoke shutdown.
       MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable(5000, camel);

       r.excecute();

       camel.run();
    }
}
```

Simple Runnable class

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    long waitingFor = -1;
    Main camel;

    public MyRunnable(long waitingFor, Main camel){
        this.waitingFor = waitingFor;
        this.camel = camel;
    }

    public void excecute(){

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);

        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                    this.wait( waitingFor );
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("camel.shutdown()");
            camel.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```